# how to fix Hibernate v6 PreLoadEvent of getState() is return always null issue?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using Hibernate 6.1.7.Final. (with spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.0.4, com.h2database:h2:2.1.214)
I registered a PreLoadEventListener in the registry and applied it to receive PreLoadEvent as a listener.

```
@Component
public class EncryptionListener implements PreInsertEventListener, PreUpdateEventListener, PreLoadEventListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onPreLoad(PreLoadEvent event) {
        Object[] state = event.getState();     // is always null T.T
        String[] propertyNames = event.getPersister().getPropertyNames();
        Object entity = event.getEntity();
        // todo: fieldDecrypter.decrypt(state, propertyNames, entity);
    }
}
```

In 6.x, when debugging, getState() always returns null.
In 5.x, it was returning the value read directly from the DB (i.e. the encrypted value before decryption).

I also attach the configuration and entity code

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class HibernateListener {

    private final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    private final EncryptionListener encryptionListener;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactoryImpl.class);
        EventListenerRegistry registry = sessionFactory.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.PRE_LOAD).appendListener(encryptionListener);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.PRE_UPDATE).appendListener(encryptionListener);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.PRE_INSERT).appendListener(encryptionListener);
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@ToString
public class Phone {
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String address;
    // getter, setter, no-argument constructor
}
```

When I downgrade the Spring Boot version to 2.x and test with Hibernate 5.x, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in Hibernate which has been fixed in https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16350

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it for a while after I bypassed it and fixed it.

Thanks to you, I'll be able to use the preload event in the future. 
Thanks.